How to fill the spherical polygon in matplotlib-3D?
I am working on drawing worldwide coastlines in matplotlib, for example:
coastlines
This is data about the Afica coastline that may be useful.
afri = np.array(
[[31.531222,    31.919167],
 [31.600389,    31.028306],
 [30.822056,    29.064944],
 [31.442056,    26.982472],
 [31.523639,    25.200833],
 [31.971056,    24.979833],
 [32.152889,    23.319944],
 [32.635389,    23.107472],
 [32.941222,    21.708306],
 [32.182056,    20.1],
 [30.850861,    20.057083],
 [30.274583,    18.989972],
 [30.925389,    17.853306],
 [31.397889,    15.741667],
 [32.382056,    15.205028],
 [32.897861,    13.388306],
 [32.837889,    12.299139],
 [33.797083,    10.214139],
 [34.187528,    10.017861],
 [35.215833,    11.162917],
 [36.135778,    10.467833],
 [37.089583,    11.039139],
 [36.712889,    10.431611],
 [37.349556,    9.745],
 [36.842917,    7.899972],
 [37.08625, 6.415806],
 [36.641194,    5.344139],
 [36.925389,    3.895861],
 [36.49375, 1.084139],
 [35.842889,    0.0],
 [35.727917,    -0.937528],
 [35.075389,    -1.9575],
 [35.108667,    -2.830083],
 [35.441972,    -2.979139],
 [35.206278,    -4.688389],
 [35.917111,    -5.470861],
 [35.790778,    -5.934639],
 [34.025389,    -6.8125],
 [32.545833,    -9.287111],
 [31.3975,  -9.846222],
 [30.071639,    -9.662944],
 [29.309139,    -10.217944],
 [28.29875, -11.525],
 [27.95625, -12.915861],
 [26.659194,    -13.65125],
 [26.196667,    -14.465417],
 [24.685861,    -14.903778],
 [23.803306,    -15.915417],
 [23.9725,  -15.704583],
 [21.798139,    -16.983],
 [20.837528,    -17.107222],
 [21.161194,    -16.912528],
 [20.224972,    -16.197917],
 [19.38,    -16.547917],
 [17.7475,  -16.04375],
 [15.697472,    -16.577056],
 [14.741667,    -17.533778],
 [13.879167,    -16.513778],
 [13.36125, -16.506667],
 [13.515806,    -15.574611],
 [13.249583,    -16.355028],
 [13.46,    -16.717944],
 [12.571611,    -16.763778],
 [12.609972,    -16.220472],
 [12.406639,    -16.77625],
 [12.345389,    -16.014194],
 [12.096667,    -16.352083],
 [11.992472,    -15.853778],
 [11.734556,    -15.955833],
 [11.988722,    -14.939167],
 [11.789167,    -15.509583],
 [11.643278,    -15.03375],
 [11.328333,    -15.504611],
 [10.997917,    -15.235],
 [11.183306,    -15.004639],
 [10.918722,    -15.078389],
 [11.076639,    -14.697083],
 [10.208722,    -14.455833],
 [9.796611, -13.537056],
 [9.506639, -13.72375],
 [9.334861, -13.303944],
 [8.531667, -13.174611],
 [8.560833, -12.837083],
 [8.421639, -13.293778],
 [7.766639, -12.45625],
 [7.384111, -12.521278],
 [6.7895,   -11.23075],
 [4.807083, -8.7175],
 [4.360361, -7.480806],
 [4.997028, -6.124167],
 [5.258389, -4.017],
 [4.754611, -1.981694],
 [5.592902, 0.0],
 [6.161167, 1.343361],
 [6.621194, 3.821639],
 [6.395806, 3.40125],
 [6.350389, 4.430833],
 [5.764528, 5.064167],
 [5.97, 5.367083],
 [5.718333, 5.080389],
 [5.619194, 5.542861],
 [5.568306, 5.17625],
 [5.390417, 5.361667],
 [5.540806, 5.680444],
 [5.163306, 5.362083],
 [4.310417, 5.983333],
 [4.338722, 6.705028],
 [4.612917, 6.723333],
 [4.359583, 6.867472],
 [4.667861, 6.779139],
 [4.372917, 7.005778],
 [4.737917, 7.075806],
 [4.443722, 7.34],
 [4.536222, 8.278278],
 [4.92875,  8.235778],
 [4.482056, 8.554972],
 [4.746667, 8.830389],
 [3.941194, 9.214167],
 [4.0975,   9.727944],
 [3.809167, 9.833694],
 [3.810833, 9.542917],
 [3.079111, 9.975417],
 [1.175833, 9.343722],
 [1.07875,  9.695972],
 [0.4525,   9.66375],
 [0.5125,   9.309583],
 [0.1725,   9.987083],
 [0.050389, 9.501667],
 [0.357917, 9.351639],
 [-0.714194,    9.130417],
 [-0.668361,    8.700389],
 [-2.408361,    9.619583],
 [-4.450861,    11.727861],
 [-5.727556,    12.167917],
 [-6.010861,    12.672944],
 [-6.14,    12.272917],
 [-8.388333,    13.392111],
 [-9.087528,    12.994583],
 [-11.008361,   13.862833],
 [-12.235028,   13.657056],
 [-13.418361,   12.532889],
 [-15.835833,   11.744556],
 [-17.979194,   11.7995],
 [-22.542611,   14.502028],
 [-26.317528,   14.94625],
 [-31.6825, 18.200444],
 [-32.530028,   18.327083],
 [-32.820028,   17.847889],
 [-34.302111,   18.399944],
 [-34.080444,   18.790806],
 [-34.830444,   20.019972],
 [-33.97875,    22.555833],
 [-34.206278,   24.839972],
 [-33.565417,   27.011639],
 [-31.297111,   30.009167],
 [-29.454194,   31.274556],
 [-28.549194,   32.385389],
 [-26.084111,   32.964389],
 [-26.292917,   32.834056],
 [-25.960056,   32.498667],
 [-24.107528,   35.502056],
 [-22.171722,   35.546222],
 [-20.555056,   34.661222],
 [-19.650833,   34.631222],
 [-19.852944,   34.885],
 [-18.877111,   36.3125],
 [-17.87875,    36.854972],
 [-16.438806,   39.856639],
 [-14.832528,   40.842111],
 [-12.928389,   40.394556],
 [-12.746694,   40.642083],
 [-11.313333,   40.332083],
 [-10.684278,   40.642056],
 [-10.031833,   39.704444],
 [-8.292528,    39.255389],
 [-7.813361,    39.447056],
 [-7.850833,    39.217111],
 [-7.0175,  39.55125],
 [-6.052528,    38.772889],
 [-4.680861,    39.201944],
 [-2.735833,    40.186278],
 [-2.264194,    40.987917],
 [-1.934167,    40.774556],
 [-1.96125, 41.314972],
 [0.714583, 43.559167],
 [2.429528, 46.011667],
 [4.4775,   47.965444],
 [9.419167, 50.830417],
 [10.314944,    50.902056],
 [10.443333,    51.415417],
 [10.420806,    51.022056],
 [11.833306,    51.29125],
 [11.986111,    50.797611],
 [11.337889,    49.426667],
 [11.179583,    47.4125],
 [10.68375, 46.440806],
 [10.867889,    45.805833],
 [10.375389,    44.575806],
 [11.612944,    43.156611],
 [11.522889,    42.527472],
 [11.988361,    43.376194],
 [12.475778,    43.327028],
 [14.623722,    41.189972],
 [14.948722,    40.209972],
 [15.507889,    39.875],
 [15.095,   39.712028],
 [18.060111,    38.557056],
 [18.875,   37.412056],
 [21.214167,    37.111194],
 [21.065,   37.31875],
 [22.063333,    36.895417],
 [22.946611,    35.667889],
 [23.934222,    35.476222],
 [23.909222,    35.79375],
 [24.513333,    35.13875],
 [27.8475,  33.586222],
 [28.976639,    32.625389],
 [29.940417,    32.478361],
 [29.935053,    32.55867],
 [31.232806,    32.284501],
 [31.531222,    31.919167]]
)

I consider continents as spherical polygons. But I want to fill the interior of each continent on the sphere, but because on the sphere, it is obviously not possible to use the fill method that suit for a plane.
I noticed that there is a plot_trisurf method in matplotlib that can input a list of points to return a surface, but obviously this method requires me to provide other points inside the polygon (otherwise the returned surface will not fit well with the sphere).
I am not a English native speaker, and I feel sorry if there is any problem on my expression.
My idea is to scan all the points on the sphere to determine if each point is inside the polygon, add into an array if so. but I don't know how to do it.
I am also puzzled by the machanism of matplotlib(plot_surface or plot_trisurf) processing these points to build the surface.

seems that the real problem is that the polygon is too accurate?
